# Как можно передать в функцию массив символов?

Tags: c++, строки, указатели

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Line
{
public:
    void Words(char line)
    {
        char str[sizeof(line)];
        strcpy(str, line);
        char* a = strtok(str, " ,.-/! # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _` { | } ~"); // во втором параметре указаны разделитель (пробел, запятая, точка, тире)
        while (a != NULL)                         // пока есть лексемы
        {
            a = strtok(NULL, " ,.-/! # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ _` { | } ~");
        }
    }
};

void main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251); // Ввод с консоли в кодировке 1251
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    Line obj; // создание объекта класса    

    char input[100];

    cout << "Введите строку для разбора:   ";
    cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));

    obj.Words(input);

    _getch();
}
```

Comment: а Вам нужен си или с++? я уже начал писать ответ, но потом понял, что такой код легче выбросить, чем что то исправлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если уж так нужно именно `char*`...

```
void Words(const char * line)
{
    char * str = strdup(line);

    // Работа со строкой str - все ваши strtok

    free(str);
}
```

Но раз уж у вас C++ - то лучше использовать именно С++, а не улучшенный C.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось

Comment: Ну, если ответ устраивает - пометьте его как принятый (птица слева от ответа). Это и есть "спасибо" на RuSO :)

Answer (score 1):

`void Words(char line)` изменить на `void Words(char *line)`, но тогда вам ещё придётся принимать размер массива или посчитать его самому, вообще советую вам использовать `std::string`